# Missing : after property id : when running aggregate function on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to run an aggregate function, to sum up all the `current bid price` of all the `category Toyota`. My code seems to look ok but I am getting errors

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6226613eeb82220b6ccbe598"),
        "user" : 12,
        "name" : "Camry",
        "category" : "Toyota",
        "description" : "Simple but smooth",
        "closing date" : "12/06/22",
        "starting bid price" : "180.00",
        "Current bid price" : "960.00",
        "auction status" : "open"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62266282eb82220b6ccbe59b"),
        "user" : 10,
        "name" : "Prado",
        "category" : "Toyota",
        "description" : "Rugged and High",
        "closing date" : "12/04/22",
        "starting bid price" : "250.00",
        "Current bid price" : "450.00",
        "auction status" : "open",
        
}
```

my code first fetches the Toyota category from the json  then it groups based on the category and it sums up the Current bid price

```
db.auction.aggregate([ { $match: { "category", "Toyota"}},
                       {$group: { _id:"$category",total:{$sum: "$Current bid price"}}} ])
```

My error

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):1:45
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the error I needed to add colon in-between category and toyota instead of a comma

```
 db.auction.aggregate([ { $match: { "category": "Toyota"}},
                       {$group: { _id:"$category",total:{$sum: "$Current bid price"}}} ])
```